# Override "Out Of Stock" message

Tags: magento2.3, catalog

Okay, I'm a dufus. I am trying to override the "Out of Stock" message displayed on the product page to "Sold Out". Currently using Magento 2.3.

Create an i18n folder in my custom theme folder, en_Us.csv file and put in the following in the file
"Out Of Stock","Sold Out!"

Cleared the cache but it's still displaying that dreaded Out Of Stock instead of Sold Out!

I have tried searching on Google and here but it seems that simple tasks like these are not documented. Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks.

Comment: filename should be **`en_US`**.csv` NOt `en_Us.csv`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change this text only for product details page and for that section which you mentioned then you need to copy the following file to your theme:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

You theme file location will be like below:

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

And update the text.

Method 2:

Create one one en_US.csv on your theme like below:

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/i18n/en_US.csv
```

And add the translation text like "Out of Stock".

Comment: I have created the en_US.csv file just like you suggested and in it there is a line that says,

"Out of Stock","Sold Out!"

But it is still displaying OUT OF STOCK on the product page.

Comment: Did you do caching and other commands.?
If not then please do that .

Comment: Yes, I cleaned the cache and flush it from command line, still displaying the default text. Really frustrating.

Comment: Once run the following command sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ app/etc/ pub/media/

Comment: @Soundararajanm, tried that with no luck. It still won't pick up the translation.